# create npm pack with React component | component.type is undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm

I created npm package with my react component. 
babel presets es2015 and react

In my component I take all children and check their type (to perform specific actions). But all children have type == undefined.
When component is directlly in my project (not installed from npm pack) everythings works fine.

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, function (child) {
        if (child.type === SomeChildComponent) { // <-- issue is here, from npm pack child.type is undefined
            defs = React.Children.map(child.props.children, c => c.props);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom propType function to validate children:

```
static propTypes = {

  children: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    const prop = props[propName];
    return React.Children.forEach(prop, child => {
      if (child.type !== SomeChildComponent) {
        error = new Error(`${componentName} children should be of type ${SomeChildComponent}.`);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Partially it is helpfull.
My component can has few different sub-components and I have to know that first child is Type1, and second is Type4. The issue I have is that webpack transform my component into the npm pack, change all class Component1 extends React.Component into the functions.

Comment: Can you add you webpack config file please? Thanks!